# Как смоделировать пошаговый бизнес-процесс в приложении?

Tags: архитектура, графы

Есть проект, условно похожий на любое такси-приложение. Мобильный апп, клиент заказывает что-то на определённую дату и адрес, «машина» выезжает, будет через 5 минут, прибыла, началась поездка, окончилась. Такие характерные шаги в бизнес-логике.

Логика может ветвиться: если сейчас состояние А, то после него могут быть состояния либо Б либо Д, и никакое другое.  После Б может быть В, после В – Г. Похоже на граф.

Вопрос: как лучше хранить и обрабатывать такую логику в бэкэнде и мобильном приложении? Что есть best practice для подобного сценария?

Придётся ли дублировать бизнес-логику в backend + mobile, или можно держать её в одном месте?

Сейчас в прототипе прямо в коде прописаны текстовые метки для каждого возможного состояния, и условия, из какого состояния какие есть возможные следующие. В таблицу БД пишем очередное состояние объекта с датой-временем. Чтобы узнать текущее состояние объекта, выбираем самое недавнее.

Мобильный клиент запрашивает «матрицу» состояний и возможных переходов между ними с бэкенда.

Сейчас чтобы поменять логику, например, вставить новый шаг в процесс, надо переписывать этот код. А в идеале, наверное, это всё должно рулиться только данными в БД?

Может, у вас в проектах встречался похожий сценарий – расскажите, как вы его решили.

Comment: а на каком ЯП вы это собираетесь реализовать? есть разные фреймворки для реализации конечных автоматов, google: finite state machine

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ЯП не имеет значения. Речь об архитектуре в целом

Comment: Зная яп, вам могут посоветовать конкретный-фреймворк, но это однозначно конечный автомат

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вставлю сюда на всякий случай ремарку, что все нижеописанное является моим мнением, и если я пишу "должно быть", то на самом деле там "должно быть на мой взгляд".

Сама по себе задача - конечный автомат.

В мобильном приложении самой логики быть не должно, приложение должно делать две (три) вещи:

- Посылать запросы на получение данных и получать сами данные.
- Посылать команды и получать на них ответы. Команды могут либо выполниться, либо в их выполнении может быть отказано (в конкретном примере из-за неподходящего состояния автомата), либо они могут провалиться по непонятным причинам, что не является ожидаемым поведением (я имею здесь в виду ответ, аналогичный 5хх в веб-разработке, и им и являющийся при использовании HTTP в качестве транспорта). Фактически я говорю про CQRS, точнее, между обычным CRUD и CQRS я рекомендую выбрать CQRS - возможно, есть и еще более подходящие паттерны. При желании это можно довести до одной команды "SwitchState [target state=XXX, parameters=[...]]", которая позволит не хардкодить конкретные стейты, хотя лучше так не делать, конечно.
- (Опционально) принимать события от сервера. В случае, если никакого реалтайма в приложении нет, этого не нужно, и можно обойтись своевременными запросами на получение данных.

Вся логика остается на бэкенде. Приложение получает текущее состояние, формирует команду и отправляет на бэкенд. Бэкенд проверяет, возможно ли исполнение команды (состояние могло измениться, либо клиент может пытаться сделать что-то не то), после чего отвечает либо отказом, либо результатом выполнения команды (которым может быть и банальный void). Если есть жесткие бизнес-требования по атомарности / необходимость хранить изменений сущности / частичные апдейты / возможность применять команды только в определенном порядке - то здесь очень хорошо зайдет event sourcing с его оптимистичной блокировкой из коробки.

Если в вопросе имелась в виду только логика переходов автомата (пример с такси меня немного смутил - мобильное приложение в таком случае вообще не знает проавтомат и просто посылает команды), то я бы публиковал его в виде схемы на сервере и подгружал при каждом запуске приложения. Так или иначе клиент должен понять, что его схема устарела, для этого в каждый запрос хорошо включать текущую версию схемы, чтобы сервер мог вовремя осадить клиент с устаревшими данными. На самом деле все зависит от ресурсов проекта и сложности схемы: если это просто конечный автомат, то проще публиковать, если там что-то сложное, возможно, проще будет забивать руками, особенно на начальных этапах проекта.